# Add one to every value in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, addition

Say I want

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

to become

```
2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 10
```

Say the first matrix is `mat`. I *thought* `mat.+1` would work but this gives

> Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: That's because the `+` operator is inherently an element-wise operation as long as the dimensions match or one of the operands is a scalar. `.+` has no definition.  `mat+1` will suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `1`, you can add a scalar to a matrix:

```
A = [1 2 3 
     4 5 6
     7 8 9]

B = A + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `ones` to create a matrix of 1s and add. Use `size` to pass the dimensions along:

```
new_mat = mat + ones(size(mat))
```

You can also use `repmat(1,size(mat))` in place of `ones`, which can create matrices with different values filled in.

Comment: Creating a matrix entirely of 1s and adding this to a matrix is wasteful, especially if the matrix is large.  MATLAB adopts a special circumstance where if you want to add every value in a matrix by the same constant, you simply use the desired scalar value and add this to the matrix.  Look at Dan's answer for more details.